# Валидации классов EF (которые являются прямым отображением таблиц БД)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, mvc, валидация

Здравствуйте, есть 1 вопрос по валидации классов EF (которые являются прямым отображением таблиц БД). Я сторонник того, чтобы разделять ограничения (`constraints`) самой БД через `fluent api + валидация` (какие-то более хитрые проверки) через переопределение метода  `Validate` интерфейса `IValidatableObject`. Но у такого подхода есть следующие минусы:

1. Повторение кода некоторых правил валидации (например, конкретное поле таблицы `IsRequired` на уровне `fluent api`, при заполнении которого пользователем приходится добавлять аналогичное правило в метод `Validate` для MVC валидации + возможно какие-то доп. проверки)
2. Невозможность выполнить `client side MVC` валидацию (`IValidatableObject` не позволяет)

Есть другой подход в целях валидации - это `DataAnnotations` атрибуты, у которых нет вышеперечисленных недостатков, но есть другое: это то, что сразу накладываются правила и на EF и на MVC валидацию, что мне кажется, не есть `best practices`.

Поэтому интересно, каким образом лучше сделать эту самую EF валидацию. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ого, ну и вопросы. Я не спец в вашей тематике, но всё же: почему часть кода, ответственная за базу данных, вообще знает о фронтэнде (ASP.NET)? По идее, база данных и ASP должны быть независимы, поэтому повторение кода не есть проблема. То есть проблема есть, можно по идее генерировать констрейнты из общего кода программно.

Comment: Я использую EntityFramework Code First(здесь сначала полностью в коде описываются с# классы проекций таблиц БД, по которым SQL server уже создает физическую БД). Поэтому все ограничения на БД прописываются именно в тех классах

Comment: @nvse: Но ведь это же не догма. Например, можно генерировать классы (C#-Entity) отдельным шагом перед компиляцией. Или (что проще) использовать [code-based configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx). Или генерировать конфиг. Или как угодно.

Comment: Да, это понятно, можно по базе именно генерировать сами классы. Но просто вопрос не в этом. БД проекта уже просто описана именно в виде тех классов с использованием EF Code First. Могу пример для какой-нибудь таблицы для наглядности привести, если это поможет.

Comment: @nvse: нет, я имел в виду не по базе. По общей «конфигурации» констрейнтов можно конструировать как Entity, так и валидацию MVC.

Comment: Забыл указать, что используется EF 4.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что asp.net mvc?

Хорошее правило - для каждой странички на сайте своя ViewModel. На viewModel навешиваете DataAnnotations атрибуты. Это стандартная практика.

Какой бы вы не использовали подход в EF, суть от этого не меняется.

Никакой прямой связи между фронт и бекэндом. Повторяются правила - пускай повторяются. У БД свой контекст - он следит за валидностю данных. У фронтэнда свой - он следит за корректностью ввода пользователя.

То, что некоторые правила одинаковы - это только сейчас и 99% будет меняться. Вдруг вам вообще надо будет к БД обращаться из десктоп-приложения?

Comment: Да, asp. net mvc

Comment: Ага, то есть для каждого poco класса, если он отвечает за какое-то представление, его желательно оборачивать в viewModel обертку, и всю валидацию (без разницы каким из тех 2-х способов) прописывать для этой обертки. Спасибо. Прямо недавно почти такой же ответ вот тут нашел: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894367/how-to-make-fluent-api-configuration-work-with-mvc-client-side-validation

Comment: @nvse, советую также посмотреть на AutoMapper - автомапиппинг viewModel'ей в poco.